# Non standard evaluation: Plot inside Manipulate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to create a notebook with a demonstration:

```
SlopeInterceptDemonstration[{mmin_, mmax_}, {bmin_, bmax_}] :=
Module[{xmax, xmin},
xmax = Max[Abs[bmin + mmin], Abs[bmax + mmax]]*1.2;
xmin = - xmax;

Manipulate[
        Plot[m*x + b, {x, xmin, xmax}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {xmin, xmax}],
        {{m, mmin, "m"}, mmin, mmax, 0.1}, {{b, bmin, "b"}, bmin, bmax, 0.1}]
];
```

If I save a notebook with a simple call ( SlopeInterceptDemonstration[{-2, 2}, {-5, 5}] ) evaluated and reopen it with a fresh kernel the demo is not displayed because xmin and xmax are not known.

Is there a way force the evaluation of these variables inside Plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DynamicModule` together with the `SaveDefinitions` option in `Manipulate` :

```
SlopeInterceptDemonstration[{mmin_, mmax_}, {bmin_, bmax_}] := DynamicModule[{xmax, xmin}, 
  xmax = Max[Abs[bmin + mmin], Abs[bmax + mmax]]*1.2;
  xmin = -xmax;
  Manipulate[Plot[m*x + b, {x, xmin, xmax}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {xmin, xmax}], {{m, mmin, "m"}, mmin, mmax, 0.1}, {{b, bmin, "b"}, bmin, bmax, 0.1}, 
   SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
SlopeInterceptDemonstration[{mmin_, mmax_}, {bmin_, bmax_}] :=
 Manipulate[
   Plot[m*x + b, {x, xmin, xmax}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {xmin, xmax}],
   {{m, mmin, "m"}, mmin, mmax, 0.1},
   {{b, bmin, "b"}, bmin, bmax, 0.1},
   {xmax, None},
   {xmin, None},
   Initialization :>
     {xmax = Max[Abs[bmin + mmin], Abs[bmax + mmax]]*1.2, xmin = -xmax}
 ]
```

`{xmax, None}` is used to localize `xmax` in the Module.  The method with `DynamicModule` shown in the other answer is standard and more flexible.